# Swapping VBA code for python

Tags: python, vba

Morning,

I have a very simple VBA code which refreshers the addin i have in excel. This is below

```
Sub Refresh()
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "FDSFORCERECALC(False)"

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

I have tried using xlsxwriter but i am unable to write anything but a macro to press which still means manually opening each file. Is there a way to automate this code into Python, so i can just iterate through files and refresh as I go?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module's COM support to manipulate the files programmatically. It will look something like this:

```
import win32com.client

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("spreadsheet.xls")
xlApp.ExecuteExcel4Macro("FDSFORCERECALC(False)")
workBook.Save()
workBook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()
```